# Op-Amp difference amplifier low-pass filter

Tags: capacitor, operational-amplifier, filter, low-pass

I have the following (summing, single supply) difference amplifier circuit:[image: summing, difference amplifier]

How can I extend this circuit to a 1st or 2nd order low pass filter, with a corner frequency at about 20kHz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I extend this circuit to a 1st or 2nd order low pass filter,
>   with a corner frequency at about 20kHz.

1st order solutions: -

Put the same capacitors across R6 and R8 is one method (maintaining R6 and R8 at the same value).

Another method is put a 1k resistor in series with the output and shunt the 10k with a capacitor (it works more perfectly with the 10k omitted of course).

---

A 2nd order circuit can be done in a balanced input configuration but I'd use a [sallen key](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPseikiLowkeisan.htm) op-amp filter after your circuit.